# How might I add an audio track to the 2D Animation dope sheet?

Tags: animation, audio

I'm hoping to animate some 2D characters based upon an audio dialogue -- is it possible to put the audio track as its own layer on the dope sheet with audible playback so I can match up the characters with their voice audio?

Thanks.

Comment: You can do this at least two ways - Sync the animation to the audio by sliding Dopesheet keyframes left and right to suit the audio track, - OR - create automatic sync something akin to this 

 - https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/145105/voiceover-in-blender/145346#145346

Comment: @Edgel3D thanks for the info -- but how do I even add an audio track to the 2D Animation Dopesheet?

Comment: Have another look at that link.  Scoll right down until you see a sub-heading called "--> POINT A <--"    This is where you add the audio file and "Bake" it to an f-curve. (graph it)  It becomes the graph that's read to expand and contract the 'sound bar' .

If you have no experience, I'd suggest setting up a new and simple project such as that shown but without the lips.  Just concentrate on getting the sound bar (an ordinary plane) expanding to the audio.

To hear the audio you can also add the file as a sound strip in the VSE. (video editor)

Comment: PS to the above - The sound graph won't be added as keyframes in the Dopesheet and chances are you won't need to anyway.  It's a different technique and not one you want to be distracted by just yet.

Comment: The [Sound Waveform Display](https://pullusb.gumroad.com/l/sound_waveform_display) addon allows to display the waveform in the timeline and dopesheet editors.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled with this question, and although it is not the specific thing been asked, I think can easily solve it.

If we remember that Blender can configure windows as we need, we can adapt it to show the waveform while editing with the dope sheet.

**1.** I choose to adapt the windows of Animation Layout. You can make a new one if you want.

[image]

**2.** Then I split the dope sheet to have a parallel window below it.

[image]

**3.** Change the new panel to a Video sequencer.

[image]

**4.** Load your audio. You can use "Shift A" to add a sound clip. Open the side panel to turn the waveform on.

[image]

**5.** Adjust the height and vertical position of the track with the scrollbar to the right.

[image]

**6.** Now you can see both the dope sheet and the waveform with a clear head position. If you play your animation the sound will play and the dope sheet (and 3D view) will run accordingly.

[image]

If the audio sounds choppy, turn the rendering of the animation to wireframe.