# Create animated textures in time with the music in blender 2.81

Tags: texturing, shaders, animation-nodes, audio

Is it possible to create an animated texture to the rhythm of music, whether they are animations of lights or texture evolutions, which follow the musical rhythm?
I have seen several tutorials on this, but I would like to adopt this method to be able to visually animate part or all of the texture, following for example the bass of a song. the texture and not the 3d object

Comment: If I read your question right, you're wanting to animate, scale, spin or distort etc, a texture either over the whole screen or on the surface of objects, all syncronised with the beat of a music track.  My own experience found it easier to produce this effect in the 3D window by firstly laying the audio track into the VSE and 'Locking' it there so it can't ever be moved.  You now have frame number references for each beat.  Textures can be animated/distorted/changed to coincide precisely with those reference frames.

Comment: could you show me the procedure with a screenshot? I'm not good yet in blender

Comment: Yes ok.  I'm going to be tied up today but will do drop an answer here and the Blend file as soon as I can.

Comment: You can also convert audio to mechanical movements in the 3D viewport and use those to distort/rotate/move a plane that holds your texture, but that conversion process is a different subject again. See here -

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/145105/voiceover-in-blender/145346#145346

Comment: I notice the same question is asked again more recently.  My proposed answer will produce the lighting effects you're after but it's not done with nodes and not in vers 2.81 either.  I won't proceed with the Blend file if the node method is desired.  Let me know thanks as it takes time to produce these things.  :)

Comment: hey, you look I posted a more detailed question since I need to interact with the parameters present in the texture nodes,to animate the texture and not the object that hosts the texture. . so if you like and you have some advice you can answer in the other question so I close this one.

Answer (score -2):

Check [HERE](https://clockmender.uk/) or [HERE](https://github.com/Clockmender) Animation Nodes Scripter

Comment: Your answer is of no help, I don't see how it can help me.

Comment: Sorry, as you said "I'm not good yet in blender" -- so your definitely not going to understand 'Animation Nodes'.

Comment: What I understand from the links in your description is that: does one take me to a github page and an alleged add on? and the other at a forum where it is explained? I don't think it is so easy to understand it by answering with simple links, without being able to understand how to adapt such things to my work. I don't know where to start.