# Turn audio into binary for simple lip syncing

Tags: audio

I'm trying out some very basic lip syncing (just two states: mouth open, mouth closed) and followed some tutorials to try and automate it. Using 'Bake Sound to F-Curves' I'm getting real close, but I can't seem to get the thresholds right or something. A seemingly simple solution seems - to me -  to be trying to fix it on the audio side.

My idea was to take an audio file and make it so that any sound above a certain volume threshold turns into a beep, and anything else becomes silent. My Google mojo has run out though and I can't seem to think of the right search terms to find my solution. Does anybody know how to do this in either Audacity or Adobe Audition? It seems so simple but I can't figure it out!

Also if this is a dumb idea and there's way easier solutions I'd gladly hear it too ;)

Comment: @josh sanfelici 's answer sums it up.  As you've been searcing for lip synching without success for your particular project, you might like to take a look here -

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/145105/voice-over-in-blender/145346#145346

Answer (score 0):

In an audio software also you will have to deal with a thresold and the workflow will end up with a trial and error system, so I think it would be better to stay into Blender (you would have to create an oscillator, add a noise gate and feed its side chain input with your audio file, setting a thresold where the noise gate would open and let the sine wave pass, setting also timing for opening and closing).

So instead, select the F-curve animated object or bone and in the 3D view go to Menu Animation > Bake action.

In this way the curve becomes editable and you can adjust it for your needs (try to simplify the curve, so that open and close states don't happen too fast).